# Is there a Javascript library for enforcing method signatures?

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js, unobtrusive-javascript, signature

I would like to have a way to specify for certain Javascript method which attributes are required, what pattern they should match, and how to respond if they are not.

This is because it results in a lot of repetitive code to check for required and optional parameters at the method level.

Take this example. Here I'd like to build a lightbox. If they send me a string, I'll display a lightbox with just content. If they send me an options object, I look for a 'title' and 'content'. Wouldn't it be great to be able to specify this in some standardized way?

```
// Static method for generating a lightbox
// callerOptions = '' //if sent a string, the lightbox displays it with no title
// callerOptions = {
//      content: '' // required popup contents. can be HTML or text.
//  ,   title: '' // required title for the lightbox
//  ,   subtitle: '' // optional subtitle for lightbox
//  }
lightbox = function (callerOptions) {
    if (!callerOptions) {
        log.warn(_myName + ': calling me without a message to display or any options won\'t do anything');
        return;
    }

    // If they send us a string, assume it's the popup contents
    if (typeof(callerOptions) === 'string') {
        this.options = {};
        this.options.content = callerOptions;

    // Otherwise assume they sent us a good options object
    } else {
        this.options = callerOptions;
    }

    _build();
    _contentLoaded();
};
```

I'd love to be able to use some library I've never heard of to do something like this:

```
// Maybe this is what it looks like with a method signature enforcement library
lightbox = function (callerOptions) {
    TheEnforcer(
    ,   {   valid: [
                'string' // assumes that it is testing type against arguments by convention
            ,   'typeof([0].title) === "string" && typeof([0].content) === "string"'
            ]
        }
    });

    // If they send us a string, assume it's the popup contents
    if (typeof(callerOptions) === 'string') {
        this.options = { 'content': callerOptions };

    // Otherwise we know they sent us a good options object
    } else {
        this.options = callerOptions;
    }

    _build();
    _contentLoaded();
};
```

Has anyone ever seen a Javascript library like this? Maybe built into one of the 1000 JS MV* Frameworks?

**Edit**:
Seems like this *is* usually taken care of by the MV* frameworks. Backbone.js has both validation and default values on it's model's properties. I think these could be used to meet, or nearly meet, the use case I present here.

Comment: I don't think you should try to force a language to behave in ways it wasn't designed to. Just my opinion.

Comment: Why not make a "helper class", which takes care of the data passed to lightbox? The lightbox should do what it is intend to do, not checking for parameters. Btw typeof is used without brackets.

Comment: The brackets here are inferring that "TheEnforcer" uses an array of arguments as test subjects. Sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 every language has its own philosophy which you should work with, not try to ignore/avoid/change. Understand why the feature works the way it does and use it to your advantage.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I disagree with these "follow the intent of the language" comments. That attitude seems like it would have prevented jQuery. I'm talking about adding a feature here, not trying to make it act like it's a classical language.

I think this would be an undeniably useful feature. As for choosing a different language, JS is essentially the only option for rich web-based interactions. The best we can do (indeed, as others have been doing) is build frameworks to add features and hope the ECMAscript committees pick up the good ones.

Comment: But you're not trying to add a feature, you're essentially trying to make the language act like it's not supposed to act. jQuery *builds on* the wonderful aspects of JavaScript--it doesn't try to change the language. Those are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are two parts to this, the philosophical/architectural and the implementation.

On the philosophical side, I think there is nothing simpler (for users of my API, not for me, the API developer) than clear expectations and error messages that describe what is and isn't required for each method.

On the implementation side, which is what the question was originally about, I think I have to answer my own. Backbone.js' Models, particularly the .validate portion, seem to fulfill this need pretty well. I have yet to use them but it's the only thing I've found like it so far.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate

EDIT:
Another solution could be compile time. Google Closure Compiler seems to handle this quite nicely: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

Answer (score 2):

*(This was intented to be a comment, but it became longer than expected.)*

I understand such a feature can be useful sometimes but I believe it should be avoided whenever possible. And I think the ECMA standard should never include that.

Take your example: a lightbox title and content are required. Why? Why not displaying an empty lightbox, without a title or content? It's a decent fallback, in my opinion. If you're building an API, whoever is using it can check for empty title and content and just not call the lightbox function if desired. Also, I don't like the idea of trying to enforce types in JS.

I think that is radically different than jQuery. They just provide a chainable wrapper object (with a bunch of useful methods inside), and favor a certain coding/syntax style, and that's most of jQuery. It makes the language look simpler, unlike type and method signature enforcing - definitely not as "Simple As Could Be" (sorry for that).